# SharePoint Export only selected list items not whole list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

Is there a way to export only individual list or library items using powershell or any other way? I tried Export-SPWeb command with item URL but it exported whole library.

Answer (score 0):

For list you can try list template. Individual items export not possible.

Still if you want you can try the long method : take list/library template for entire library --> create new library with new name --> delete unwanted list items --> create list template from this new library to get desired items.